# Why do my two PCs have different Wifi speed of the same router?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router

I recently bought a Lenovo laptop with Wifi card "Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 3160" to replace an old Acer laptop whose wifi card is "Qualcomm Atheros AR5B97 Wireless Network Adapter", and both are running Windows 7 OS.

However, they are having significantly different internet speeds in the same Wifi environment, and apparently the older one is much faster.

I have tried to manually configure the IP addresses, but it didn't work. Or, is it a problem of the router?

Because recently there has been a difficulty in auto-assigning IP addresses to my Macbook (I manually assign IP address to it, and its speed is as good as the older Windows laptop).

Comment: How are you testing the speed? are you streaming both at the same time? is the slow laptop always slow even if it is the only one connected? did you check the advance settings of the wireless adapter? what is your router? does it multi-bands?

Comment: @Logman I use Speedtest.com for speed tests. Yes, they are running at the same time, and the slow one is slow anyway. The router is Belkin N150 150 Mbps 4-Port 10/100 Wireless N Router, there are no options for bandwidth adjustment.

Comment: When running speedtest, disconnect the internet cable or power-off the laptop with the faster connection. When you've done that, run speedtest again on the laptop with the slower connection.
BTW, disconnect every device using internet to get the best test results.

Comment: @CoproManiac The speed difference is still there. I found that the slower laptop's wifi speed is changing over time. Sometimes the download speed could reach approximately 1Mb/s, and sometimes it's like 0~9 kb/s. But the ping is always good, less than 20 ms.

Comment: You tried test on power supply connected? If on battery, it possible effect of power saving.

Comment: @mmv-ru Yes, I'm sure the power adapter is connected.

Comment: Check on router, If encryption used, use AES, not TKIP. Intel say, TKIP incompatible with high speed (802.11n) (Different vendors has different point of view on it)

Comment: @mmv-ru It is AES already.

Comment: Try doing the test twice - once with both computers right next to the router, and once a few rooms away. BTW, exactly how big is the speed difference we're talking about here?

Comment: @user54791 The slower one's speed is usually 10kb/s, and the normal speed is over 1 Mb/s. And the slower one wasn't this slow (normal speed actually) until I removed the original win8 and installed win7 on it.

Comment: If speed degraded after OS change, (and anyway it good idea) try latest Intel drivers for chip-set (if exists) and wireless. In place of integrated in Windows.

Comment: I connected the slower laptop to the hotspot of my iPhone(AT&T, LTE), and the Internet speed was good. So I assume it's a problem of the router and I've ordered a new one from Amazon.